# using include() with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the latest wordpress and I want to have an include statement:

I have a file inside my childtheme thus:

childtheme/tadincludes/includeme.php

In my functions file I have done:

```
function tadpole_form(){
echo '<p>hello</p>';
$wally='/tadincludes/includeme.php';
include($wally);
}
```

If I just have the echo statement it works fine. When I just have the include statement I get a pile or errors including  "include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0..."

So i figure I am doing it wrong.

How should I get this to work please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the leading slash...it's directing you to the theme root. Also, don't hard-code the absolute path using `/wp-content/etc/etc`, as has been suggested in another answer.

This should work: `$wally='tadincludes/includeme.php';`

Comment: `ABS_PATH` should not be hard coded, that is a wordpress constant, and easier to use, when you develop a plugin, what has effects on front end and in `wp-admin` directory. With relative path, you always need to use a condition, where are you, on the frontend, or on the admin...

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the full path of your file, what is surely not in your `document_root/tadincludes/includeme.php`. It should be `ABS_PATH . "/wp-content/themename/childtheme/tadincludes/includeme.php` or relativ path to your current directory.

Comment: Thanks. Tried using an absolute path - and that was the error I mentioned.